# How to upgrade an Azure 2.3 project to Azure 2.4?

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I just formatted my computer, installed VS2013 U3 and then Azure SDK 2.4.1 (via WebPI).

Opened up my solution and all my **azure cloud services failed to load**:

> Azure Cloud Services\MyProjectFoo.ccproj: The application which this
>   project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for
>   further information:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=CC5FD16D-436D-48AD-A40C-5A424C6E3E79

Awesome... Not.

**Can someone please tell me how I can 'upgrade' my projects, please?**

Comment: I also faced the same problem. I closed Visual Studio and opened it again and everything started working fine (I know, really lame solution :)).

Comment: Nope, didn't work for me :( Still unable to load it .. even when I manually try to reload it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out.

I installed (in order)

- Visual Studio 2013
- Microsoft Azure SDK 2.4.1 (The red box...)

[image]

thinking that 2.4.1 was all the tooling, etc.. but it's not!

So *after* I installed Microsoft Azure Tools 2.4 for MS Visual Studio 2013 ... restarted VS and opened my solution, I was then asked to upgrade my azure clients!

[image]

#### Conclusion

the SDK != VS tooling.

Comment: Thanks, this got me pointed in the right direction - mostly diff versions: VS 2015 and Azure SDK 2.7....yes, install the Tools update for VS 2015 and it prompted to convert.  All good now.  BTW, used Web Platform Installer - just search for Azure and then sort by release date to find whats needed.  Enjoy!