# Cannot load Azure 2.7 project in solution after upgrading VS 2013 Community to Professional

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, upgrade

Due to insoluble local referencing issues, I decided to uninstall VS 2013 Community edition and re-install it; as most of my team is using Professional I used that version when re-installing. ReSharper worked okay out of the box, but when I loaded my solution, our Azure project came up marked "(incompatible)".

Googling brought me [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26335668/how-to-upgrade-an-azure-2-3-project-to-azure-2-4) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556901/visual-studio-2013-2015-cant-load-azure-project), both from SO, though Googling the UUID of the failing project type, `CC5FD16D-436D-48AD-A40C-5A424C6E3E79`, didn't help much further. So far, I have used the Web Platform Installer 5.0 to install:

- Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.7.1 (used by our Azure project)
- Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2013) - 2.8.2 (latest at time of writing)
- Microsoft Azure Cross-platform Command Line Tools
- Microsoft Azure PowerShell 0.9
- Microsoft Azure PowerShell

Has anybody come across this particular case? I have attempted restarting VS as suggested in the other questions but nothing "comes up" or asks me to "upgrade my client", so now I'm at a loss.

Thanks hugely in advance.

Comment: Interestingly when I attempt to create a new Azure/cloud-based project, the IDE prompts me to install the Azure SDK. So it definitely can't "see" that I have 2.7 and 2.8 installed!

Answer (score 0):

Following several attempts to reinstall VS 2013 Pro, I decided to "reset Windows" (Windows 10) and just install VS from scratch. After doing this and installing Azure 2.7.1 from the Web Platform Installer 5.0, I loaded my solution and now Visual Studio is recognising the Azure SDK and the Azure project loads perfectly.

"Total Wipe" is never a great answer, but it worked for me in this scenario. {:¬\